# 14.04 disable a users mail

Tags: users, postfix, imap

Everything I can find with "google" says delete account, I need the account, but I need to prevent it being able to send mail.  The account is public and doesn't need mail at all.

Ideally I need it not to have access to mail, alternatively I need to drop all mail to/from this account.

A

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/q/530406/346811

Comment: I thought it was good, but it broke everythng instead, after so much fscking about with postfix, I'm going to spear it in spamassassin.